# The integral of $ \sin(x^2) $

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, power-series

The actual problem is: Find the first four nonzero terms and the general term of the Maclaurin series for $g(x) = \int\sin(x^2)dx $ with $g(0) = 1$.

How do you find the integral of $\sin(x^2)? $ I know that you are supposed to convert it into power series, but how do you actually take an integral there?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: it gives the so-called Fresnel-integral

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You know that
$$ \sin x = \sum_{j=0}^\infty (-1)^j \frac{x^{2j+1}}{(2j+1)!},
\sin x^2 = \sum_{j=0}^\infty (-1)^j \frac{x^{4j+2}}{(2j+1)!}
$$
this series can be integrated termwise.
$$ g(x) = \int \sin x^2\,dx = \sum_{j=0}^\infty (-1)^j \int \frac{x^{4j+2}}{(2j+1)!} dx
= \sum_{j=0}^\infty (-1)^j \frac{x^{4j+3}}{(4j+3)(2j+1)!} + C
$$
Then substitute $x = 0$ to find $C$.

Comment: Well, looks like I need to go to E.SE to ask about the difference of "termwise" and "termwisely".

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Thanks. It is fixed.

Comment: Can I ask what happens to the constant (1?) when expanding the series? Will it simply not exist because of the (-1)^j? @Henry W.

Comment: @KER $\sin 0^2 = 0$ so the constant term is $0$.

Answer (score 2):

*Specifically:* The primitives of $\sin(x^2)$ are not elementary, so you don't calculate them.

**Hint for the problem:** Recall that $g'(x)=\sin(x^2)$. And that the Maclaurin expansion of $g$ is $$g(0)+g'(0)x+\frac{g''(0)}{2}x^2+\cdots+\frac{g^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n+\cdots$$